# Hive Serde Properties with 'Windows-1252'

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am using a Hive table with the following properties

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `csv_test`(
  `k1` string,
  `k2` string,
  `k3` string,
  `k4` string,
  `k5` string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'escape.delim'='\\',
  'serialization.encoding'='windows-1252')
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
```

i load the data in csv into the hive.

CSV DATA:

```
AAA,2015-11-26 11:29:18,comment,group-1,nameofperson
BBB,2016-11-10 11:27:17,comments,group-2,
```

The Output for the query select * from csv_test is

```
AAA     2015-11-26 11:29:18     comment group-1 nameofperson
BBB     2016-11-10 11:27:17     comments        group-2 ameofperson
```

The serialization of 'Windows-1252' is picking the wrong value of the last field.

It is taking the above text after ',' of the last field i.e, ameofperson

If i change the serialization to  'utf-8' or others

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `csv_test`(
  `k1` string,
  `k2` string,
  `k3` string,
  `k4` string,
  `k5` string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'escape.delim'='\\',
  'serialization.encoding'='utf-8')
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
```

and fire the query select * from csv_test

Then the output is coming correct

```
AAA     2015-11-26 11:29:18     comment group-1 nameofperson
BBB     2016-11-10 11:27:17     comments        group-2 NULL
```

Why is the serialization 'windows-1252' working like this.

I need 'windows-1252' as my source file is encode with it and need the same serialization to get Unicode values.

So is there a workaround to make this work with 'windows-1252' encoding?

Comment: http://www.thedatastudio.net/hive_load_correct_character_set.htm

Comment: Why are you using serde properties with no defined serde?

Comment: Hi serde properties are given by default. i used alter command to update it.


# Storage Information
SerDe Library:        org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe

InputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat     

OutputFormat:           org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat

Comment: Okay, and that should work, so something else must be wrong... By the way, you can just use `STORED AS TEXTFILE` as a shortcut to giving the input and output formats